# Looking for the right word for error. "Tendency"?

Tags: word-request, sentence-choice

I am looking for the best way to describe in a report what I am observing in a experiment.

There are cars (or objects) in front of me, and my system is inferring a property of them (for example their direction). The inferences of the objects *right in front* of me are quite accurate (so the error is 0). However, the inference of the object 5 meters to the left has a small error. The inference of the object 5 meters to the right has almost the same small error (but negative). The inference of the object 10 meters to the left has a bigger error (same as 10 meters to the right).

I want to convey in a paragraph that I have observed this tendency, that the system's inferences have an error that is kind of proportional to how far the object is from the center. I am tempted to use the word "displacement", as in displacement proportional to the distance from the center. How can I convey this in technical writing?

Comment: Your system has a ***narrow focus***, or ***poor peripheral accuracy***. There are many ways of expressing this, but you probably won't need an entire paragraph unless you're going into much greater detail than that.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

> The magnitude of the error is proportional to a car's distance from the origin.

Of course, "magnitude" and "distance" are normally non-negative. If you want to account for negative values, then something like this may be better:

> The error value is proportional to a car's displacement from the origin.